# Learning verb conjugation

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I would like to train a network to conjugate verbs and recognize verb conjugations. For example:

- Given "To eat, 1st person, past continuous", the model would return "I was eating"
- Given "I was eating", the model would return "To eat, 1st person, past continuous"

The benefit of training would be to have the model conjugate and recognize verbs it hasn't seen previously.

I would like to train the network on standard conjugation tables such as http://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-english-verb-eat.html.

Is this within the realm of possibilities with our present machine learning technologies?

EDIT: If yes (and it seems to be the case), hints for suggested architectures or actual implementations would be most welcome.

Comment: Absolutely. Study [Character-Word LSTM Language Models](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/E17-1040) and [Grammar Inference Using Recurrent Neural Networks](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/ee3d/30287b87272c5d6efc54d4da627a59e0a816.pdf). Welcome to the site.

Comment: This is certainly possible in the scope of machine learning, the idea is to build a model that helps identify a part of the sentence that it should pay attention to